# How to keep one unique object synced across devices with iCloud?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, icloud, cloudkit

The original question was "How to keep one unique object synced across devices in near **real-time** with iCloud?" and based on the comment which seems impossible to be done with iCloud alone.

What if the acceptable delay is less than 30 seconds? would that be something possible with iCloud or CloudKit? How it can be achieved?

---

I have a `user` object which contains multiple properties update by the user at a relatively high frequency (1 update per second), and it needs to be synced across devices.

**NSPersistentCloudKitContainer**
I have tried a regular Core Data entity, but it seems hard only to allow one Core Data entity instance. A simple fetch and update would simply result in multiple instances of the same object unless adding some custom merging logic in place.

**NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore**
I also tried to explore sync UserDefault with `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` on the documentation page; there is [a big highlight of not using it for value change very frequently](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/icloud/synchronizing_app_preferences_with_icloud).

> The key-value store is intended for storing data that changes infrequently. As you test your devices, if the app on a device makes frequent changes to the key-value store, the system may defer the synchronization of some changes to minimize the number of round trips to the server.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with CloudKit.

Comment: what if the acceptable delay can be less than 30 seconds?

Comment: You probably need to look at some sort of publish/subscribe system aimed at iot.

Comment: FWIW: in my experience, iCloud response time with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer is absolutely unreliable. Sometimes a big transaction is near-instant, sometimes it takes a minute to update a boolean.